# Facebook login troubleI app Android

Tags: java, android

I have the following class that I instantiate from my fragment:

```
public class FacebookLogin {
    private CallbackManager mCallbackManager;
    private LoginButton lButton;
    private AccessToken accessToken;
    private Profile profile;
    private static final String TAG = "FacbookLogin";

   public FacebookLogin(Context c) {
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(c);
        mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        Log.i(TAG, " Constructor called");
    }

    private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> mCallback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

            Log.i(TAG, " logged in...");

            AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
            profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile(); //Access the profile who Is the person login i
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            Log.i(TAG, " Error");
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }

    };

   public void setCallback(LoginButton lButton) {
       lButton = lButton;
       lButton.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, mCallback);
       Log.i(TAG, " setCallback called");
   }

    public CallbackManager getCallbackManager(){

        return mCallbackManager;
    }

    public Profile getProfile() {
        return profile;
    }
}
```

And here Is my fragment-class:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    fLogin = new FacebookLogin(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.login, container, false);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    final LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    final TextView infoText = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.text_details);

    loginButton.setFragment(this);


    loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");

    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i(TAG, " Button clickde");
            fLogin.setCallback(loginButton); //Let's register a callback
            profile = fLogin.getProfile();
            if (profile != null) {
                Log.i(TAG, profile.getName());
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "NULL....... inside onresume");
            }
        }
    });

}
```

As you can see, Im trying to get the users profile when you click on the button. The login works, but the problem I have Is that when I click Login, else-statement Is executed and prints out NULL...... However, when I click Logout, I get the correct information, and the profile-object Is no longer NULL.

Why Is It null the first time I click on the button (login), and then becomes true when I click on It again (logout)?

When I place the profile-code inside onResume, It works. Why?

```
   @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        profile = fLogin.getProfile();
        if (profile != null) {
            Log.i(TAG, profile.getName()); //Prints out directly when I hit the button
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "NULL....... inside onresume");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an interface for solving this.

In the FacebookLogin class

```
OnFacebookListener facebookListener;
public interface OnFacebookListener{
    void onFacebookLoggedIn(Profile profile);
}
public void setFacebookListener(OnFacebookListener onfacebooklistener){
    this.facebookListener=onfacebooklistener;
}
```

and then

```
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
        profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        facebookListener.onFacebookLeggedIn(profile);
    }
```

then in your fragment

```
fLogin.setFacebookListener(new OnFacebookListener(){
    @Override
    public void onFacebookLoggedIn(Profile profile){
      //Do whatever you want to do with profile
    }
});
```

Hope this works for you :D

Comment: This worked, thank you :). Can u explain this code and how this interface helps me?

Comment: Basically interface acts as a mechanism of interaction between two different parts of the app. So in the first block you are just creating the interface. In the second block of the answer, you trigger the function in the interface when the onSuccess function is executed. When this function is triggered, it executes the code written in third block.

Comment: Imagine it this way. You are cooking something in the microwave. So you set the microwave to some time and do some other work. You want to be notified when cooking is done. So after the timer stops the microwave sets off an alarm to notify you that cooking is finished and then you do whatever with the cooked food.  Microwave can be considered as the FacebookLogin class, loggin in as cooking food and the fragment activity as the other work you are doing. The interface works as an alarm in this case. Facebook Login -> Interface called -> function executes in main thread.

Comment: How do you get the profiles friends via the graph API? Or how do I get the taggable friends? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32682827/get-taggable-friends-using-the-graph-api

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Facebook Graph Api for getting user details from facebook. Here is the login code I used for my project.

```
loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            /**
             * Current SDK uses GraphAPI to retrieve data from facebook
             */
            final String token = loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken();
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject jsonObject, GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                    String name1 = jsonObject.optString("name");
                    String email1 = jsonObject.optString("email");
                    JSONObject cover = jsonObject.optJSONObject("cover");
                    String coverPic = cover.optString("source");
                    String id = jsonObject.optString("id");
                    String userdp = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "/picture?type=large";
                    loginSocial(Constants.POST_METHOD_FACEBOOK, token);
                }
            });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,cover");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Cancelled... Please try again later", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Failed... Please try again later", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Read my question again please. I only want the name of the person who logs In, and you can get that i with getName().

Comment: What do  mean? Can you be more specific?

Comment: For what I see is that in the code
    
    fLogin.setCallback(loginButton); //Let's register a callback
    profile = fLogin.getProfile();

The login method (i.e. contacting fb) is executed asynchronously.  So while the actual login is happening in background, the main thread executes the profile=fLogin.getProfile(). 
At this time profile is null. The profile is assigned only after logging in from fb server. 

In short, you are calling profile=fLogin.getProfile() before fb actually logs you in.

Comment: Anyone who can help me?